# Should I unaccept an answer and reopen my question or submit a new one with further details?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question found here:
[System.Timers.Timer Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661881/system-timers-timer-usage)
The answer to the question is great and appeared to work perfectly but upon debugging the program today, I noticed theres a small chance (maybe 1-10% I still don't know as it happens too randomly and I haven't tested it enough) that the suggestion he provided will malfunction completely and the returned string from the device I'm using won't be caught correctly. Now this doesn't appear to be a fault in his suggestion as much as it's either a flaw in Serial Port connections or an inherent bug in the SerialPort class.

In this case, should I unaccept the answer and ask for further clarification as the info may help other users in the future? Or should I submit a new question entirely as my question differs almost completely as it now appears there's an inherent flaw somewhere and it isn't a case of a bad answer.

EDIT: If you'd like I can include a bit of code and explain my reasoning as to why I think the answer is permissible despite the faults I'm experiencing but I don't currently see it as pertinent to this question.

Comment: add a new question and link back to the old one. A link to the new one will magically appear at the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think that un-accepting an answer that was "great" - because there remains some additional work to do - especially when you consider it may be due to a bug in a library - is likely to discourage the person who provided that answer from providing additional help.

If the poster of the answer that you have already accepted is relatively new to SO then the loss of reputation may strike them as ungrateful.

By all means follow the advice given by @Kate Gregory above - it sounds good to me.